# Conjugate of basic expression not simplified

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Why does Mathematica not simplify the following expression?

```
assumptions = {a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, c \[Element] Reals}
FullSimplify[Conjugate[I a b + c (I b + c)], Assumptions -> assumptions]
```

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[I a b + c (I b + c)]]`

Comment: `assumptions = {(a | b | c) \[Element] Reals};
Simplify[Conjugate[I a b + c (I b + c)] // ComplexExpand, assumptions]`

Comment: Thanks, `ComplexExpand` does the job.